# Concatenating to an Optional Array with the "+=" operator

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, xcode6-beta6

I'm trying to append multiple strings to an array.
This code works as expected:

```
var myArray: [String] = []
myArray += ["dog", "cat"]
```

This gives me an error:

```
var myArray: [String]! = []
myArray += ["dog", "cat"] //error: '[String]!' is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

Is this a bug, or is concatenating to an optional Array not supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myArray` is an optional, and as such you have to explicitly unwrap it in order to make the append work:

```
myArray! += ["dog", "cat"]
```

That sounds counterintuitive, because the purpose of the implicitly unwrapped optional is to avoid manual unwrapping. However the documentation says that:

> An implicitly unwrapped optional is a normal optional behind the scenes, but can also be used like a nonoptional value, without the need to unwrap the optional value each time it is accessed

My explanation is that, being the optional an enum under the hood, the `+=` operator is applied to the enum and not to the actual type wrapped by the optional itself.